# Need to pass an HTML ID for an image into a variable in javascript to use in various functions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to use code from html into javascript using code from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-the-id-of-the-clicked-button-using-javascript-jquery/.

I am creating a memory game I have the images stored in an array and am able to click on it and it flips. I want to take the ID of 2 images and compare them but I need to pass the clicked ID variable from html into a javascript variable to store them for processing:

Here is my code for the detectClick function

```
**function detectClick(clicked) { 
                htmlID = clicked; 
                return htmlID;}**
```

Here is my HTML sample of my table of the first 4 array elements:

```
***<tr class ="success"  >
            <td onClick="changeimage('tblArr0',tblArr[0]);"><img src='memImages/CardBack.png' id="tblArr0"
            onClick="document.getElementById('tblArr0').src='tblArr[0];detectClick(this.id);';"draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart_handler(event)"></td>  
            <td onClick="changeimage('tblArr1',tblArr[1]);detectClick(this.id);"><img src='memImages/CardBack.png' id="tblArr1"
            onClick="document.getElementById('tblArr1').src='tblArr[1]';"draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart_handler(event)"></td>
            <td onClick="changeimage('tblArr2',tblArr[2]);detectClick(this.id);"><img src='memImages/CardBack.png' id="tblArr2"
            onClick="document.getElementById('tblArr2').src='tblArr[2]';"draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart_handler(event)"></td>
            <td onClick="changeimage('tblArr3',tblArr[3]);detectClick(this.id);"><img src='memImages/CardBack.png' id="tblArr3"
            onClick="document.getElementById('tblArr3').src='tblArr[3]';"draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart_handler(event)"></td>
          </tr>***
```

I need to pass the detectClick(this.id) into the variable htmlID.

Any other ways of doing this or suggestions would help.

I have the the `tblArr[]` which contains another array called `imgArr` which stores the source name of the files for the images. I am able to have my array shuffled, now I need to be able to process the array objects to compare them. I just need to know how to get the ID from the image back into a javascript variable.

Thanks for suggestions and help in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

This should create your `<td>`s for as many as are available in the array:

```js
function detectClick(clicked) { 
  htmlID = clicked; 
  return htmlID;
}
  
function loadSuccess() {
  let container = document.getElementById("success");
  for (let i = 0; i < tblArr.length; i++) {
    let new_td = document.createElement("td");
    new_td.setAttribute("onClick", "changeimage('tblArr" + i + "',tblArr[" + i + "]);");
    container.appendChild(new_td);
    
    let new_img = document.createElement("img");
    new_img.src = "memImages/CardBack.png";
    new_img.id = "tblArr" + i;
    new_img.setAttribute("onClick", "this.src='tblArr[" + i + "];detectClick(this.id);';");
    new_img.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
    new_img.setAttribute("ondragstart", "dragstart_handler(event)");
    new_el.appendChild(new_img);
  }
}
```

```html
<tr class ="success" id="success" onload="loadSuccess()"></tr>
```